# How do I run multiple proxies on Tor for windows?

Tags: anonymity, firefox

Also, will I have to disable firewall? I am fairly new to Tor, so dumb it down as best as you can. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please describe in more detail what you try to do? What are the proxies you ask about?